# Compute the pullback of a differential 1-form along the inclusion $i:S^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

As in the question, I am given the 1-form $xdy-ydx+zdt-tdz\in\Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^4)$ and I am asked to compute its pullback $i^*\alpha\in\Omega^1(S^3)$ via the inclusion $i:S^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$.

I know the general definition of pullback, and I know how to proceed in the "calculus case" where we pull back along maps $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, but I have never seen an example of explicit computation in the more general case, here I expect it to be easier since we have embedded varieties, but it would be a start).

Can someone please help me developing the computation?

Comment: I think that there is nothing to do. The pullback is the abstract way of describing the change of variables. If the coordinates that you use on $\mathbb S^3$ are $x, y,z,t$, then you already have your result. If you want to use another coordinate system, then you have to do some computations.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro ok, the fact is, I am asked to show that this form never vanishes on the sphere

Comment: And in similar exercise I am asked instead to find the zero locus of forms: I have not the faintest idea of how to do this

Comment: Dear Francesco, it is better if you edit the question. I don't really know how to help you right now. Buon lavoro

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I will, grazie e anche a te !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer one of your questions in the comments, namely why $i^*(\alpha)$ is a non-vanishing 1-form on $S^3$.

Choose a point $p = (a, b, c, d) \in S^3$, so $i^*\alpha$ restricts to a linear functional on the tangent space $T_{p}(S^3)$. If $v \in T_p(S^3)$ is any tangent vector, then $v$ and $p$ (viewed as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$) must be perpendicular, i.e. we must have 
$$av_x + bv_y + cv_z + d v_t = 0$$
In particular, this implies that the vector 
\begin{align}
v_1 := \langle -b, a, -d, c \rangle
\end{align} 
is tangent to $S^3$ at $p$.

Now, observe that 
\begin{align}
i^*(\alpha)|_p(v_1) &= a (a) - b (-b) + c(c) - d (-d) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1 \neq 0.
\end{align}
Therefore $i^*(\alpha)|_p$ is not the zero functional. This argument works for any point $p$.

Remark: this argument is essentially saying that the vector field given by $v_1$ is non-vanishing as a vector field on $S^3$.